# Static variable that does not retain its value

Tags: c, variables, static, minimum, retain

I want to write a function minimum to return the minimum  value that was sent to it in between calls. The function can receive any number of arguments, all of which are integers in the range 0 through 100. The end of the list of arguments sent to the function is represented by -1.

For example, if I entered the following calls in `main`:

```
minimum (90,78,5,20,-1);
minimum (70,40,2,-1);
minimum(40,30,-1);
```

The first call will return 5 because the minimum value of 90,78,5,20 is 5.
The second call will return 2 because the minimum value of 5,70,40,2 is 2
The third call will return 2 because the minimum value of the  2,40,30 is 2.

So the function `minimum` returns the minimal number that was sent to it in all the calls that occurred so far.

So I created a static variable called `min` to retain the value of the minimum between the function calls.

Here is what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int minimum(int cnt, ...)
{
   static int min;
   int cur_min,i;
   va_list lst;

   va_start(lst,cnt);
   cur_min = va_arg(lst,int);
   min = cur_min;

 printf("min is %d and cur min is %d \n", min, cur_min);
    for(i=0; i<cnt; i++)
    {
        if(cur_min != -1)
        {
            if(cur_min < min)
            {
                min = cur_min;
            }
           cur_min = va_arg(lst,int);
           printf("min is %d and cur min is %d \n" , min, cur_min); 
       }
       else
           break;

    }

      va_end(lst);

    return min;

   }





int main()
{





  printf("In Call One: min is %d \n",minimum(90,78,5,20,-1));
  printf("In Call Two: min is %d \n", minimum(70,40,2,-1) );
  printf("In Call Three: min is %d \n", minimum(40,30,-1) );


    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following output:

```
In Call Two: min is 2 
In Call Three: min is 30
```

While the output should be:

```
In Call Two: min is 2
In Call Three: min is 2
```

It seems like although I've declared the variable `min` using the `static` keyword, `min` does not retain its value in between calls.

Why and how can I make `min` retain its value in between function calls?

Comment: Please consider formatting your code correctly, and remove those useless blank lines.

Answer (score 6):

Static variables do retain their values between calls.  However, please allow me to direct your attention to a few lines in your code:

```
cur_min = va_arg(lst,int);
min = cur_min;
```

You do this immediately upon entering the function.  So, while `min` *would* have had the value from the last pass, you are overwriting it in *every* pass.

Comment: Can you please explain it in a little more detail? If I understand it well then the line cur_min = va_arg(lst,int); min = cur_min; will be performed only once - before entering into the for loop. Why would that overwrite something? Isn't this an initialization? I understand static variables retain their value, but in my case it seems like it does not, since if it were, it would have the value 2 in the next call (which is call three).
Thanks!

Comment: It is done only one time before the for loop.. but it is done *every time you call the function*.  This is why you are overwriting the previous value of `min`

Comment: If I understand it well, then since min is a static variable, it gets initialized only once. If it is so, then why would the line
 cur_min = va_arg(lst,int); min = cur_min; be executed each time I call the function? Should not min get initialized only in the first call to the function?
Thanks

Comment: `min = cur_min;` is not *initializing* the variable. Initialization is done when you first declare the variable, either implicitly to zero (`static int min;`) or explicitly (`static int min = 3;`). Writing `min = cur_min;` is just setting the variable to the value of cur_min, not initializing it. Not 100% sure, but writing `static int min = va_arg(lst,int);` should do the trick.

Comment: Actually I understand why the line cur_min = va_arg(lst,int); would be executed each time the function is called, but I do not understand why the line
min = cur_min; would be executed each time the function is called, because as far as I know a static variable is initialized only once.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What you are referring to is not initialization. You are simply setting its current value. Initialization is setting its initial value.

Comment: Thank you, still, I do not understand, why is not this initialization? I mean, 
I declared min like so static int min; without intializing  it. So when I write

Comment: Thank you very much, now the difference is clear. 
I tried writing static int min = va_arg(lst,int); but I got a compile error:
main_call.c In function minimum
main_call.c:9:4: error: initializer element is not constant 
static int min = va_arg(lst,int);

With an arrow pointing to the keyword 'static'.  @Razbit

Comment: Thanks! @David Hoelzer

Comment: Ah, yes.  You can't do that.  It sounds like you've got it now.